# Como selecionar um <option> do <select> com javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Tenho dois `selects`, um para funcionário e outro para função, sendo que preciso que quando um funcionário for selecionado a função dele já seja selecionada automaticamente.

Esse `alert` funciona perfeitamente, mas preciso que no lugar dele seja um código para selecionar um `option` do `select` de funções de acordo com o `data-funcao` do funcionário selecionado.

```
$('#funcionario').on('change', function() {
    alert($("option:selected", this).attr('data-funcao'));
});
```

Select de funcionários:

```
<select id="funcionario" name="funcionario">
    <option value="..." data-funcao="...">...</option>
...
</select>
```

Select de funções:

```
<select id="id_mfuncao" name="id_mfuncao">
    <option value="...">...</option>
...
</select>
```

> Estou usando o plugin jquery **select2**, não sei se influencia em algo...

Comment: Testa `$('#id_mfuncao').select2('val', $("option:selected", this).attr('data-funcao'));` no lugar do alert. Acho que é isso. Testa e diz aqui.

Comment: Po funcionou sim @Sergio, vlw!

Comment: Alguém sabe como fazer sem jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O select2 tem um método `.select2` que serve quase para tudo. Passando `val` no primeiro argumento e um valor no segundo ele vai procurar nos options quem tenha esse valor. Assim podes usar:

```
$('#funcionario').on('change', function() {
    var escolhido = $("option:selected", this).attr('data-funcao');
    $('#id_mfuncao').select2('val', escolhido);
});
```